# How to take information from input out of a while loop?

Tags: python, input, while-loop

My explaining is horrible so Ill put an example what I mean

```
s=5
while s >= 3:
    name= input("What is the name of your dog")
    s = s-1
```

this isnt the best piece of code but lets say I wanted to ask the user for a piece of information and they will input 3 different times so how can I take all those 3 value out of the while loop so that they dont get overwriten? If Im not bieng clear please tell me I will try to explain myself better

Comment: Use a `list` to store the input

Comment: Wrap this in a function and "yield" each time in while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list before the while loop begins, and append an entry every time the loop runs:

```
s=5
names = []
while s >= 3:
    name= input("What is the name of your dog")
    names.append(name)
    s = s-1
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the quick response

Answer (score 1):

using generators:

```
names = [input("What is the name of your dog") for i in range(3)]
print(names)
```

using list:

```
names = []

s = 5
while s >= 3:
    name = input("What is the name of your dog")
    names.append(name)
    s = s - 1
```

using yield:

```
def names():
    s = 5
    while s >= 3:
        yield input("What is the name of your dog")
        s = s - 1

for name in names():
    print(name)

# or

print(list(names()))
```

A different solution for your task:

```
names = input('write all the names: ').split()
print(names)
```

Comment: Given the poster is clearly a beginner, I do wonder if introducing them to generators is the best idea. For such a small loop, memory usage will not be an issue, so list creation seems just fine

Comment: Sorry another quick question Following on from my last question I was wondering If its possible to have a print change the value of what its printing on the list by itself for example since I dont know how to format here is a screenshot of the code [link]{http://puu.sh/qwdu3.png) 'code'

Comment: you can access the last element with `lst[-1]` where `lst` is the name of your variable. read the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/).

Comment: the second `while` should be an `if` i guess

Answer (score 0):

Use List

```
s=5
name = []
while s >= 3:
    name.append(input("What is the name of your dog"))
    s -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a list where you can append the names to.

```
names = list()
s=5
while s >= 3:
    names.append(input("What is the name of your dog"))
    s = s-1

print names[0]
print names[1]
print names[2]
```

Comment: it gives me raw_input is not defined

Comment: @rauf543 ah, I'm just using an old version of python. ```input``` should be fine